# Make an unknow height img vertical middle with CSS and support IE9

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

```css
.box {
    width : 100%;
    max-height : 300px;
    overflow : hidden; 
}

img {
     width : 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <img src="banner.png" />
</div>
```

I don't know the size of the image banner.png but I want to limit the `max-height` of `.box` element. If the height of banner.png is larger than the `max-height` I need to make the img tag vertically middle.

How can I make that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
.box{
width : 100%;
max-height : 300px;
overflow : hidden;
}
.box > img {
    width : 100%;
    max-width:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to smoething like this.

**Updated answers**

```
.box {
 width : 100%;
 max-height : 300px;
 overflow : hidden;
}
.box img {
 width:100px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But I don't want to change the size of the image.

Comment: I have update my code. Please check. it's work without change image height

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code using flex**

```
.box{
width : 100%;
max-height : 300px;
display:flex;
align-items: center;
}
```

```css
.box {
    width : 100%;
    min-height : 300px;
    overflow : hidden;
    border:1px solid green; 
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <img src="http://c5.la4.download.9appsinstall.com:7080/group1/M02/6D/74/pYYBAFhLFviAdm8mAAAWl_5Xbaw477.png" />
</div>
```

**Using position**

```css
.box {
    width : 100%;
    min-height : 300px;
    overflow : hidden;
    border:1px solid green; 
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}

.box img {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <img src="http://c5.la4.download.9appsinstall.com:7080/group1/M02/6D/74/pYYBAFhLFviAdm8mAAAWl_5Xbaw477.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Cuz I need to support IE9, may be `display : flex;` can not work in IE9 .

Comment: yes, I tried that way, but  the img's position is not correct if I didn't specify the height of the `.box` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.box {
    width : 100%;
    max-height : 300px;
    overflow : hidden; 
    display: flex;
}

.box img {
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Begining with 10 http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox IE9 Very little user

Comment: My mean was in IE 9 as per question